# Group objects by keys in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash, data-manipulation

I have an array of objects. These objects have a property called "type".

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "type": "Plane",
    "date": "date",
    "value": "10",
    "another_value": "10"
},
{
    "id": "1",
    "type": "Plane",
    "date": "date",
    "value": "15",
    "another_value": "10"
},
{
    "id": "1",
    "type": "Car",
    "date": "date",
    "value": "25",
    "another_value": "10"
},
{
    "id": "1",
    "type": "Car",
    "date": "date",
    "value": "25",
    "another_value": "10"
}]
```

Now, I have a table where I want to display this. I want to display it in two rows, one **row** for "Plane" and one **row** for "Car" and in that row I want like the total sum of (value, and another_value)

So I'm thinking this is easiest accomplished by somehow going through my original array of objects and grouping them by "type". So I'll get an array of all objects with the type "Car", and one with "Plane".

I have lodash available, then I also need to find a way to **sum** the values, so I can display it in my table, in a column on each row.

Any advice on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with plain JavaScript, using methods like [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
const arr = [{
    "id": "1",
    "type": "Plane",
    "date": "date",
    "value": "10",
    "another_value": "10"
},
{
    "id": "1",
    "type": "Plane",
    "date": "date",
    "value": "15",
    "another_value": "10"
},
{
    "id": "1",
    "type": "Car",
    "date": "date",
    "value": "25",
    "another_value": "10"
},
{
    "id": "1",
    "type": "Car",
    "date": "date",
    "value": "25",
    "another_value": "10"
}]

const sum = (a, b) => Number(a) + Number(b)

const cars = arr.filter(x => x.type === 'Car')
const planes = arr.filter(x => x.type === 'Plane')

const carsValue = cars.map(x => x.value).reduce(sum)
const planesValue = planes.map(x => x.value).reduce(sum)

const carsAnotherValue = cars.map(x => x.another_value).reduce(sum)
const planesAnotherValue = planes.map(x => x.another_value).reduce(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first group all the objects by `type`, and then reduce all the `value` and `another_value`:

```
var types = _.groupBy(array, 'type');
var result = _.mapValues(types, function(value, key) {
  return _.reduce(value, function(memo, v) { 
    return memo + +v.value + +v.another_value;
  }, 0);
});
```

```js
var array = [{
    "id": "1",
    "type": "Plane",
    "date": "date",
    "value": "10",
    "another_value": "10"
},
{
    "id": "1",
    "type": "Plane",
    "date": "date",
    "value": "15",
    "another_value": "10"
},
{
    "id": "1",
    "type": "Car",
    "date": "date",
    "value": "25",
    "another_value": "10"
},
{
    "id": "1",
    "type": "Car",
    "date": "date",
    "value": "25",
    "another_value": "10"
}];

var types = _.groupBy(array, 'type');
var result = _.mapValues(types, function(value, key) {
  return _.reduce(value, function(memo, v) { 
    return memo + +v.value + +v.another_value;
  }, 0);
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Another approach

```
var count = _.countBy(data, 'type');
var sum = _.reduce(data, function(total, obj) {
    total[obj.type] += Number(obj.value);
    return total;
}, {
    Car: 0,
    Plane: 0
});
```

```js
var data = [{
    "id": "1",
    "type": "Plane",
    "date": "date",
    "value": "10",
    "another_value": "10"
},
{
    "id": "1",
    "type": "Plane",
    "date": "date",
    "value": "15",
    "another_value": "10"
},
{
    "id": "1",
    "type": "Car",
    "date": "date",
    "value": "25",
    "another_value": "10"
},
{
    "id": "1",
    "type": "Car",
    "date": "date",
    "value": "25",
    "another_value": "10"
}];

var count = _.countBy(data, 'type');
var sum = _.reduce(data, function(total, obj) {
  total[obj.type] += Number(obj.value);
  return total;
}, {
  Car: 0,
  Plane: 0
});

console.log(count['Plane']);
console.log(count['Car']);
console.log(sum['Plane']);
console.log(sum['Car']);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```